# Make a backup of files

Tags: c#

So, I make a program to make a backup of some particular file, with particular extensions, so, I enter with List or array with the extensions of I whant to make a backup

```
List<string> extensions = new List<string>();
extensions.Add("*.pdf");
extensions.Add("*.txt");
extensions.Add("*.inf");
extensions.Add("*.doc");
extensions.Add("*.cpp");
extensions.Add("*.cs");
extensions.Add("*.vb");
```

Ok, but, how I can make the search system, to find the files with that extensions in folders..

the search system is simple:

```
    public void DirSearch(string sDir)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.pdf"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(f);
                }
                DirSearch(d);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
```

Ok, but, how I can make this to search for all extensions in list ( to make a most rapid system ), and, the program can not enter on windows folder..., if I set the sDir = "C:\"

Answer (score 1):

To simply extend what you have you're going to need another loop, one that iterates the extensions and calls `GetFiles` based on the current, though "to make a most rapid system" is highly ambitious at this level. Anyway,...

```
foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) {
  foreach (string e in extensions) {
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, e)) {

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use overload [`GetFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) with option `SearchOption.AllDirectories`, so you don't need to call recursively, also use LINQ with `SelectMany`:

```
var result = extensions.SelectMany(e => 
                       Directory.GetFiles(sDir, e, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

**Update:** To ignore protected folder, you can use `try catch` to skip exception:

```
private string[] GetFiles(string directory, string pattern)
{
    try
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(directory, pattern, 
                                       SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return new string[0];
    }
}
```

So:

```
var result = extensions.SelectMany(e => GetFiles(sDir, e));
```

Comment: good, but, how I can make, to system not enter in windows folder, for example ?

Comment: @Alexandre: I'm afraid I don't understand your question, please could you elaborate more?

Comment: so, for example, if I put sDir = @"C:\", the system will try to enter on windows folder, so, how I can make, to system not enter on windows forlder ?

Comment: @Alexandre: you means the system files?

Comment: @Alexandre: please could you update your question including this point, that would be more clear what you expect

Comment: @Alexandre: you should limit this based on your input sDir, something like: sDir should not begin with "C:" or "D:" just specify the correct folder

Comment: Ok, I did it, but, when the system try to enter on documents and settings I got an error: access denied... and, when I try to enter on user folder, like desktop, i recive the same error ( I have tryed with adm privileges )

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extra loop or recursion, just use overloaded `Directory.GetFiles` which will get all file names recursively

```
    public void DirSearch(string sDir)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string item in extensions)
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sDir, item, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(file);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply multiple search criteria but seperating the value with a semi-colon

```
*.vb;*.txt
```

So you can simply generate the search string using the list

```
var search = string.Join(";", extensions.ToArray());
...
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, search))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be slightly more performant to call GetFiles(string Directory) and get the results back into a single list, and then parse that.  The following snippet should do what you need...

```
var extensions = new List<string> { ".pdf", ".txt", ".inf", ".doc", ".cpp", ".cs", ".vb" };
var files = Directory.GetFiles(topLevelFolder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var matching = new List<string>();
foreach (var ext in extensions)
{
    matching.AddRange(files.Where(f => f.EndsWith(ext)));
}
```